# How can I remove page numbers for the first two (blank) pages for a LyX-based book?

Tags: lyx, page-numbering, book-design, front-matter

I am using LyX to produce a book. I start with \frontmatter. The first two pages (in the default PDF) are almost blank. (I want those pages to appear.) Those pages have page numbers ("1" and "2"). I do not want those page numbers to appear. (After those pages, the title page has no page number and the back of title page has a page number of "ii". Both of these pages have, regarding page numbering, what I want. Also, all frontmatter page numbering is in headers, which is what I want.)
How can I direct LyX to remove the page numbers for (just) the first two "blank" pages?

LyX file:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass book
\begin_preamble
\date{}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize custom
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\paperwidth 8in
\paperheight 10in
\leftmargin 1in
\topmargin 0.9in
\rightmargin 0.7in
\bottommargin 0.5in
\secnumdepth 2
\tocdepth 2
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 2
\paperpagestyle headings
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout LyX-Code
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
frontmatter
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Title
book title
\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
mainmatter
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code
placeholder statement
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you give a minimal example .lyx file? It is just a text file so you can paste it in here as code. Please see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: I created a file that produces the error. Hopefully, the following is what you want. (I copied-and-pasted the material I see.) If not, please let me know what to do.\frontmatter

book title

\mainmatter

placeholder statement

Comment: I cannot see where you pasted the code. Can you paste it into your original question (click on "edit").

Comment: @scottkosty Thanks for your patience and persistence. (I am new to LyX and to Stack Exchange. Perhaps I do not understand how to proceed. [Your further advice might help me!] However, ... "the following text" is the entire contents my computer-screen shows regarding what exists regarding the example I created. I copy-and-pasted it from the computer-screen display. There are just two \... items and just two "dummy content" items ["book title" and "placeholder statement"]. That [or, "the following text"] is all there is:) \frontmatter book title \mainmatter placeholder statement

Comment: Save your LyX document to a file. e.g. myfile.lyx. Then open that file in a text editor. That is what you want to copy and paste in here as code.

Comment: @scottkosty Again, thanks for your patience and persistence. I tried to do what I think you suggested. Apologies for the volume (and format) of the text. But, as yet, I do not know what better I could/should do regarding conveying the info. Also, assuming there is a 'fix' for the problem, please advise as to how I can insert the fix into my document.

Comment: @TBJ thanks for adding a minimal example. This will be useful for your next question. Please always include minimal examples. Hopefully the solution by Torbjørn T. will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `\pagestyle{empty}` in  the ERT right before `\frontmatter`.

[image]

Comment: TT, SK: Thank you. (TT:) The added character string worked. (SK:) You helped get 'this' and 'my working knowledge' to the point that someone could offer a solution.